# ASP.net Data binding non empty rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, dataset, datalist

I have a 200 rows in my datatable which there are a lot with "" (string.empty) values, so I need to remove them from my datatable before data biding.

I don't know how to data binding an array

My datalist:

```
<asp:DataList
      id="list1"
      runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <cc1:SWCLabel 
             runat="server"
             Text ='<%# Eval("myfield1")%>'
              />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

// My code behind
DataView view = dt3.DefaultView;
DataRow[] rows = dt3.Select("myfield1 <> ''");
... // Something here
```

Plese, assist me with non linq solutions since I'm not capable to undertand it at the moment.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Linq`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> dataSource = dt3.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("myfield1")));
list1.DataSource = dataSource;
list1.DataBind();
```

Comment: It throws me a runtime exception saying me that System.Data.DataRow does not contain a property with name "myfield1".

Comment: @senyortoni: The same if you convert it to a `DataTable` again? `list1.DataSource = dataSource.CopyToDataTable();`. Does the table really contain a `DataColumn` with name "myfield1" which is of type `string`?

Comment: Yes, it contains this field, and does not crash when databind without linq filter.

Comment: Where do you get the exception(look at the stacktrace). Are you using the [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx) event? I'm suprosed since your original approach uses a `DataRow[]` which is nearly the same as the Linq approach. You can call `dataSource.ToArray()` to create a `DataRow[]`  if you want.

Comment: Excellent!! It works and does not crash, but... is this linq way efficient?

Comment: @senyortoni: It's as efficient as the old `dt3.Select` approach(maybe even more since it's strongly typed). But the most efficient is to filter not in memory but in the database via sql.

Comment: okey, since this data comes to me via HOST I cannot filter. Solved but I would appreciate a not linq solution.